# Modeling DB Validation Tables in Hibernate

Tags: java, postgresql, hibernate

To Simplify, following is the sample data model.

```
USER                        STATUS
========  >|------------|-  ======
id                          status
username
password
status
```

Is there a different way to model Validation tables in hibernate? Also, a single table can have more than One Validation Tables.

I want to create Enum for Status Entity on Hibernate side which has data populated from database. And from User Entity I can refer to Status Entity Enum for accessing values. And if possible avoid ManyToOne relationship on User Entity.

I tried to look into hibernate documentation and couldn't find anything over there. May be I have missed something. Any reference to documentation could also help.

I am aware of how to model ManyToOne relationship in hibernate. If no other way exist, then I am planning to go ahead with ManyToOne.

Comment: Please be more descroptive

Answer (score 0):

You can create an enumeration in the postgresql itself,  refer the link for get to know  [how create enumeration in the postgresql](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/datatype-enum.html)

Comment: I am not looking for enums on postgres end. I am trying to include enum on hibernate end. May be I was not clear before. I have just added more description.